# Algorithm to partition a graph under constraints

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

What would be an algorithm to partition the vertex set of an undirected graph into 2 vertex disjoint subsets such that each vertex has at most  $\left\lfloor\frac{d}{2} \right\rfloor$ no of its neighbors in its partition where d is the degree of the vertex?

Comment: What does it mean to partition it? do you delete the edges stemming to other partitions? or do the vertices need to be disjoint from the very start to be in different partitions?

Comment: I meant partitioning the set of vertices of the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a random partition into $2$ parts. If there is a vertex $v$ in any part that violates the desired condition move it to the other part. This process eventually stops since every time we make such a move the number of edges between the two parts increase by at least $1$. Eventually a maximum is reached and you end up with the desired partition.